# cakephp test post body

Tags: php, unit-testing, cakephp

I have a client software which sends the data inside the POST-body of each request. Inside my CakaPHP application I access check the data with the following code:

```
// StationController.php
if ($this->request->is('post')) {
    $data = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'), TRUE);
    ...
}
```

The problem now is, how to write a test case which simulates the POST request with the correct body content? Here is my current test case which does not work correct:

```
/**
 * testPoints method
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function testPoints() {
    $data = array(
        'Station' => array('id' => '123'),
        'points' => array(
            array('id' => 1, 'sensor_id' => 1, 'value' => 25.43, 'sync' => 0, 'timestamp' => 1407063842),
            array('id' => 2, 'sensor_id' => 2, 'value' => 52.5, 'sync' => 0, 'timestamp' => 1407063842),
            array('id' => 3, 'sensor_id' => 3, 'value' => 934.566, 'sync' => 0, 'timestamp' => 1407063842),
            array('id' => 4, 'sensor_id' => 4, 'value' => 867.2, 'sync' => 0, 'timestamp' => 1407063842),
            array('id' => 5, 'sensor_id' => 1, 'value' => 25.93, 'sync' => 0, 'timestamp' => 1407064081),
            array('id' => 6, 'sensor_id' => 2, 'value' => 53.5, 'sync' => 0, 'timestamp' => 1407064081),
            array('id' => 7, 'sensor_id' => 3, 'value' => 935.566, 'sync' => 0, 'timestamp' => 1407064081),
            array('id' => 8, 'sensor_id' => 4, 'value' => 665.57, 'sync' => 0, 'timestamp' => 1407064081)
        )
    );
    $data = json_encode($data);

    $result = $this->testAction(
        '/stations/points/1',
        array('data' => $data, 'method' => 'post')
    );

    debug($result);
}
```

How to modify testAction to add some POST data?

Comment: Note: usually you can just use `$this->request->data = $this->request->input('json_decode', true);`

Comment: I didn't know the `$this->request->input('json_decode', true);` method before and this solved my problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I use

```
$this->request->data = (array)$this->request->input('json_decode', true);
```

in this case.
You can then use request->data just as you normally would.

Pro-tip: You can also combine both the "application/x-www-form-urlencoded" one and the plain post one:

```
if (!$this->request->data) {
    // Only then manually retrieve input
    $this->request->data = (array)$this->request->input('json_decode', true);
}
```

That also means you can simplify your tests and use the array notation for post data for them - as it is more difficult to mock php input here.